# Why do I get "Host not found" when using a restricted Squid proxy in Elinks?

Tags: squid, elinks

I want to block in elinks the Yahoo sites (`www.yahoo.com` and all its subdomains `fr.yahoo.com`, etc). I tried with Squid (`squid.conf`):

```
acl Badsites dstdomain .yahoo.com
http_acces deny Badsites
```

and in `elinks.conf`:

```
set.protocol.http.proxy.host = "proxy.host:3128"
set.protocol.http.proxy.user = ""
set.protocol.http.proxy.passwd = ""
```

but it doesn't work. It tells me `Host not found` on every site I try to access. Do you have any idea why it behaves that way and can you tell me a solution?

Comment: Shouldn't `http_acces` be `http_access`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write `localhost:3128`, and you missed the sintax a little, it's `set protocol.http.proxy.host`, without the first dot.